# modify dataframe in pyspark with rdd function

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Below is the dataframe for patient activity month wise

```
 rdd = sc.parallelize([("00000000000087052962",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
    ("00000000000087052963",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)]
                        )
df=rdd.toDF(['PTNT_GID','m_200402','m_200407','m_200408','m_200501','m_200503','m_200504','m_200505','m_200506','m_200508','m_200509','m_200512','m_200604','m_200605','m_200607','m_200608','m_200609','m_200611','m_200612','m_200701','m_200703','m_200705','m_200708','m_200709','m_200710','m_200711','m_200712','m_200801','m_200803','m_200804','m_200805','m_200806','m_200807','m_200808','m_200809','m_200810','m_200811','m_200812','m_200901','m_200902','m_200903','m_200904','m_200905','m_200906','m_200907','m_200908','m_200909','m_200910','m_200911','m_200912','m_201001','m_201002','m_201003','m_201004','m_201005','m_201006','m_201007','m_201008','m_201009','m_201010','m_201011','m_201012','m_201101','m_201102','m_201103','m_201104','m_201105','m_201106','m_201107','m_201108','m_201109','m_201110','m_201111','m_201112','m_201201','m_201203','m_201204','m_201205','m_201206','m_201207','m_201208','m_201209','m_201210','m_201211','m_201212','m_201301','m_201302','m_201303','m_201304','m_201305','m_201306','m_201307','m_201308','m_201309','m_201310','m_201311','m_201312','m_201401','m_201402','m_201403','m_201404','m_201405','m_201406','m_201407','m_201408','m_201409','m_201410','m_201411','m_201412','m_201501','m_201502','m_201503','m_201504','m_201505','m_201506','m_201507','m_201508','m_201509','m_201510','m_201511','m_201512','m_201601','m_201602','m_201603','m_201604','m_201605','m_201606','m_201607','m_201608','m_201609','m_201610','m_201611','m_201612','m_201701','m_201702','m_201703'])
```

Use case: I want track patient activity for last 36 months. patient should have active once( flag is 1 or 0 as mentioned in dataframe ) every six month for last 36 month then activation flag set for that month is 1 otherwise 0.

i wrote below logic to modify the dataframe. start month is m_200402 and end month is m_201703.No need to check  first 36 month  for each patient i have to track activity from 37th month.

```
def chunkify(alist, wanted_parts):
    length = len(alist)
    return [ alist[i*length // wanted_parts: (i+1)*length // wanted_parts] 
             for i in range(wanted_parts) ]

result = []
#result.append(df.columns)
for i,data in enumerate(df.rdd.map(list).toLocalIterator()):
   result.append(data)
   for j,val in enumerate(data):
       if( j > 37):
        falg = 1
        for jndex,ts in enumerate(chunkify(data[j-37:j-1], 6)):
          if 1 in ts:
              flag = 1
              result[i][j] = 1
          else: 
              flag = 0
              result[i][j] = 0
              continue

result =[df.columns] + result
```

I want to modify above logic in data frame itself using lambda functions in pyspark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explode your dataframe in order to have one row by `PTNT_GID, month`, then apply a window function.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
from itertools import chain
df_expl = df.select(
    'PTNT_GID', 
    psf.posexplode(psf.create_map(list(chain(*[(psf.lit(c), psf.col(c)) for c in df.columns if c != 'PTNT_GID'])))))

    +--------------------+---+--------+-----+
    |            PTNT_GID|pos|     key|value|
    +--------------------+---+--------+-----+
    |00000000000087052962|  0|m_200402|    0|
    |00000000000087052962|  1|m_200407|    0|
    |00000000000087052962|  2|m_200408|    0|
    |00000000000087052962|  3|m_200501|    0|
    |00000000000087052962|  4|m_200503|    0|
    |00000000000087052962|  5|m_200504|    0|
    |00000000000087052962|  6|m_200505|    0|
    |00000000000087052962|  7|m_200506|    0|
    |00000000000087052962|  8|m_200508|    0|
    |00000000000087052962|  9|m_200509|    0|
    |00000000000087052962| 10|m_200512|    0|
    |00000000000087052962| 11|m_200604|    0|
    |00000000000087052962| 12|m_200605|    0|
    |00000000000087052962| 13|m_200607|    0|
    |00000000000087052962| 14|m_200608|    0|
    |00000000000087052962| 15|m_200609|    0|
    |00000000000087052962| 16|m_200611|    0|
    |00000000000087052962| 17|m_200612|    0|
    |00000000000087052962| 18|m_200701|    1|
    |00000000000087052962| 19|m_200703|    1|
    +--------------------+---+--------+-----+
```

Now we can apply a window function. If I understand correctly you split the last 36 months into 6 chunks of 6 months. The final value is 1 if and only if each of the 6 chunks contains at least one 1. This translates into the minimum over the 6 chunks of the maximum value over the 6 months

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy('PTNT_GID').orderBy('pos')
res = df_expl.select(
    "*",
    psf.least(
        *[psf.max('value').over(w.rowsBetween(-(i+1)*6 - 1, -i*6 - 1)) for i in range(6)]
    ).alias("act_6m")
).na.fill(0)
    +--------------------+---+--------+-----+------+
    |            PTNT_GID|pos|     key|value|act_6m|
    +--------------------+---+--------+-----+------+
    |00000000000087052962|  0|m_200402|    0|     0|
    |00000000000087052962|  1|m_200407|    0|     0|
    |00000000000087052962|  2|m_200408|    0|     0|
    |00000000000087052962|  3|m_200501|    0|     0|
    |00000000000087052962|  4|m_200503|    0|     0|
    |00000000000087052962|  5|m_200504|    0|     0|
    |00000000000087052962|  6|m_200505|    0|     0|
    |00000000000087052962|  7|m_200506|    0|     0|
    |00000000000087052962|  8|m_200508|    0|     0|
    |00000000000087052962|  9|m_200509|    0|     0|
    |00000000000087052962| 10|m_200512|    0|     0|
    |00000000000087052962| 11|m_200604|    0|     0|
    |00000000000087052962| 12|m_200605|    0|     0|
    |00000000000087052962| 13|m_200607|    0|     0|
    |00000000000087052962| 14|m_200608|    0|     0|
    |00000000000087052962| 15|m_200609|    0|     0|
    |00000000000087052962| 16|m_200611|    0|     0|
    |00000000000087052962| 17|m_200612|    0|     0|
    |00000000000087052962| 18|m_200701|    1|     0|
    |00000000000087052962| 19|m_200703|    1|     0|
    +--------------------+---+--------+-----+------+
```